# Code first, multiple foreign keys

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

First of all let me apologize for the poor title, I'm not quite aware of what to call this topic.

Anyways..

I'm trying to create a `BankAccount<-->Transactions` relation using code first.

Here are my "entity classes"

```
public class BankAccount : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }

    public virtual long UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> FromTransactions { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> ToTransactions { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual long ToId { get; set; }
    public virtual BankAccount To { get; set; }

    public virtual long FromId { get; set; }
    public virtual BankAccount From { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I would like a transaction to be able to have a "From" `BankAccount` and a "To" `BankAccount` for making it easy to navigate from a transaction to the belonging BankAccount(s). Also the `BankAccount` has two collections of transactions, one "From" and one "To", and that's also to make it easy to navigate between the objects.

The thing is that as soon as I run `Update-Database` it fails with:

> Conflicting changes to the role 'BankAccount_ToTransactions_Source' of the relationship 'OpenFridge.Api.Data.BankAccount_ToTransactions' have been detected

I also have added the two following `EntityTypeConfigurations`:

```
public class BankAccountEntityTypeConfiguration : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<BankAccount>
    {
        public BankAccountEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("BankAccounts");

            HasRequired(e => e.User)
                .WithMany(e => e.BankAccounts);

            Property(e => e.Balance)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(e => e.Name)
                .IsRequired();

            HasMany(e => e.ToTransactions)
                .WithRequired(e => e.To).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

            HasMany(e => e.FromTransactions)
                .WithRequired(e => e.From).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

public class TransactionEntityTypeConfiguration : BaseEntityTypeConfiguration<Transaction>
    {
        public TransactionEntityTypeConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Transactions");

            Property(e => e.Amount)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(e => e.From);

            HasRequired(e => e.To);
        }
    }
```

Any idea of how to create this kind of relation in a proper way? I might simply be missing something in my database-design as well..

Br,
Inx

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, a quick fix for update-database that fails (if you're still in the design phase) is to delete the database and run update-database again to build from scratch. Occasionally, errors have to do with sequence of events as you change your model. 
Another check you can make is to run `update-database -script` and run the resultant SQL in the database manually.
The final quick fix I can offer is to delete the offending relationship in the database.

To help you in the future it may help to use data annotations in your model `[Required] [Key] [ForeignKey("ForeignKeyId")]` can be helpful in specifying how everything connects and reduce code in your configurations to just the relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the names of your foreign keys in the `Transaction` entity like so:

```
public class Transaction : BaseEntity
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }

    public virtual long ToId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToId")]
    public virtual BankAccount To { get; set; }

    public virtual long FromId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromId")]
    public virtual BankAccount From { get; set; }
}
```